# Need linq query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have 3 fields(Name, Code, displayNmae) in the list, here I need to get a list as output in which I get all the fields but need to split displayname field by colon and then add list again for each splitted value which is display name.
Hence in output list I will have the 5 row as total display name are 5 in 2 rows.
Need the linq query for this problem.

**Name              Code                    displayName**

Napkins_tableware - Napkins and tableware - 3_ply:conventional_napkins

hand-towel        - Hand and Towel        - 2_ply:towel roll:coloured

Output should be like this :

**Name**                **Code                  displayName**

Napkins_tableware - Napkins and tableware - 3_ply

Napkins_tableware - Napkins and tableware - conventional_napkin

hand-towel        -  Hand and Towel       - 2_ply

hand-towel        -  Hand and Towel       - towel roll

hand-towel        -  Hand and Towel       - coloured

---

### Solution which I tried in C#

```
foreach(ProductDetailsWithFilters qs in CategoryProductList())
{
    foreach(string friendlyname in qs.displayName.Split(':'))
    {
        qs.displayName = friendlyname;
        tempCategoryProductList.Add(qs);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far, and what is not working?

Comment: I am trying to do through for each loop against display name, spliting displayname and then assigning whole list in new varaible with each splited value.

Comment: Okay, show us the code that you've tried, and tell us what isn't working...

Comment: But I don't want to use for each of C#, I need to achieve all through linq only. because through c#  code will become very complex and if  I use Linq then it will be very robust and simple.

Comment: If it were as simple as you say it is, you should be able to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're translating to LINQ, when you have nested foreach loops those correspond to 'from' clauses in query syntax (or in dot syntax, subsequent ones become SelectMany, see below.) The following should be close to what you want:

```
var query = 
    from qs in CategoryProductList()
    from friendlyName in qs.displayName.Split(':')
    select new ProductDetailsWithFilters(qs.Code, qs.Category, friendlyName);
```

Note: Because functional programming should be side-effect-free, it's better to select a new instance `ProductDetailsWithFilters` than it is to modify the existing one in your query. My presumption is that you can call a constructor to build a new one of these.

For you to modify the existing property like your loop implementation does, you would have to iterate over the result -- LINQ doesn't provide such a thing in the framework. Such side-effects often lead to hard-to-find bugs.

To do the equivalent of the above query with a SelectMany and dot-syntax:

```
var query = CategoryProductList()
    .SelectMany(
        qs => qs.DisplayName.Split(':'),
        (qs, friendlyName) => new ProductDetailsWithFilters(qs.Code, qs.Category, friendlyName));
```

Both lead to functionally identical code. In this case, I tend to prefer the query-syntax over the dot-syntax partly because because there are several SelectMany overloads and handling the projection involves repeating the variables across both lambda expressions. If you had another "from" to add, the query-syntax hides the management of 'transparent identifiers' that you would otherwise have to deal with in dot-syntax equivalent code. Whatever your preference, you now have both.

It's worth noting that queries are lazy -- they do nothing until you iterate over their result. So it's really what you do with the result from here that is the interesting part - store it .ToList(), directly data-bind it to a UI, use it to service a web-API, etc...